# Import Data step from csv ignores encoding

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to import a UTF-8 encoded file into SAS enterprise Guide 6.1 M1 64-bit. But the encoding seems to be troublesome to get EG to import correct.

My csv file, called TESTÆØÅ.csv contains the following data:

```
TESTÆØÅ
ÆØÅæøåäÄöÖ
```

I am using the Import Data step from the File menu. I do change the encoding to `Unicode (UTF-8) (Code Page 65001)` in step 1 and in the preview, it shows the correct visualisation.

[image: Encoding chosen]

But when the actual work is run, EG interpers the heading row correct, but the data is interpreted with `LATIN-9` encoding.

[image]

This is verified by the `INFILE` part of the data step in the log:

```
INFILE 'THE_PATH#LN00024'
    LRECL=20
    ENCODING="LATIN9"
    TERMSTR=CRLF
    DLM='7F'x
    MISSOVER
    DSD ;
```

How can I get EG to actually use `UTF-8` as encoding for the data as well?

Comment: I also tried to copy the actual data step and changing the acutal encoding to `UTF-8` running it as a `Program`. This returned `ERROR: Invalid string.` and `FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.` So it might be something with the enviroment.

Comment: Are you using a utf-8 for the SAS session?

Comment: No, `LATIN9` is used according to `proc options option=encoding`.